# why does this do times lisp loop giving me issues?

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

Am trying to implement the function element I that return the i-th element of the list.car of the list is element 0,1 etc and I'm trying to use the dotimes loop together with the pop function and I keep getting errors

```
(defun element-i (y L)
;; (setq m )
  (let ((m ( cdr L));;(return car L))
    (dotimes(m (cdr L) t)
      (if (equal y 0) (return car L)
     (pop car L)
       (setq i (+ m L)))))))
```

Comment: im new to this language

Comment: While you already have a good answer to some of your problems you should consider to spend some time to study the excellent resources give e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/common-lisp/info). 

Get used to CL's syntax and style, give more details about the errors you get etc. will help to give you better feedback and specific answers for specific questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a number of issues here. First, you are using a parameter `y` but inside the function you call it `i`. Further `L` is a list, so `(+ m L)` will signal an error. On the other hand, I think you intend to use `m` as an integer, but you initialize it as `(cdr L)` which is a list.
Also, the function `pop` modifies the list `L`, but it's much easier to use a variable to point at the next element of the list, without modifying the list, simply by saying `(setq m (cdr m))`.
You can rewrite the function in a simpler way, thinking along these lines: take a variable `m` and initialize it to `L`. Loop `i` times through the list, making each time `m` equal to `(cdr m)`, i.e. the same list minus the first element of the previous loop. Once you exit the loop `m` will be the sublist whose car is the `i`-th element of `L`.